# QT Blackberry 10 cascades get WIFI IPv4 address programmatically

Tags: qt, wifi, blackberry-10, ipv4, blackberry-cascades

I required IPv4 address of my blackberry device of WIFI which it is connected.

The IPv4 address which is displayed in Settings -> About -> Category Network => WIFI

The same address I have to access programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/device_comm/wifi/cascades_wifi_overview.html), the Wifi service is only available in C.

If you don't want to deal with C, I think that reading the file mentionned down below with PPS and mixing `default_gateway` first entry with `fib` should give you the correct IPv4, but I'm not sure as I don't know much about networking lingo.

`/pps/services/networking/all/status_public`

You'll find [many](https://github.com/RodgerLeblanc/TheUnexposedAPIs/blob/master/src/WifiWatcher/WifiWatcher.cpp) [many](https://github.com/RodgerLeblanc/TheUnexposedAPIs/blob/master/src/RadioManager/RadioManager.cpp) example on how to read files with PPS on my GitHub or in the [official documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__ppsobject.html).